# Databinding does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `MainPage.aspx` I have

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"http://google.pl"%>'>test</asp:HyperLink>
```

It does not add an `href` tag but only outputs `<a>test</a>`.
When I do:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='http://google.pl'>test</asp:HyperLink>
```

It works fine.

Why `<%#"http://google.pl"%>` does not work ?

How to debug it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot output HTML literals into asp control properties. You can either set the hyperlink NavigateUrl property in codebehind or output the html anchor as a literal.

Output as a literal (in this case your codebehind class must expose a protected or public property or field named UrlParams)

```
// site.aspx
<a href="<%="http://google.pl" + UrlParams.Google%>">test</a>
```

Set in codebehind:

```
// site.aspx
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="link1">test</asp:HyperLink>
// site.aspx.cs or <script runat="server">..</script>
protected void Page_Load(..) {
    link1.NavigateUrl = "http://google.pl" + UrlParams.Google;
}
```

And the answer to your original question. The `<#` is a [data-binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), that  creates a binding between a server control property and a data source.

**EDIT:** As it turns out, you can actually use the `<#` syntax with strings too. The key for it to work is to call the [Control.DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databind.aspx)() method. You can call it on the HyperLink control or even on the current Page, since Page inherits from Control.

Example: (put this in an empty aspx page - no datasources required):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "#Test" %>'>Test</asp:HyperLink>
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
        // or: 
        // link1.DataBind();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me but this actually works:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvTest" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="test" NavigateUrl='<%#"http://google.pl"%>' runat="server">test</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
    lvTest.DataBind();
}
```

if you want to mix the datasource with the literal you can do it like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="test" NavigateUrl='<%#"http://google.pl?page=" + Container.DataItem %>' runat="server">test</asp:HyperLink>
```

You should use Eval instead of Container.DataItem if you want to access specific property. BTW all this is bad practice. You should use the ItemDataBound (or similar event) and bind using strongly typed C# code.

Comment: +1 it works, but the key is the DataBind() call. You don't need a control with a DataSource. See my updated answer.

Comment: Calling DataBind with no data source is totally pointless except in some hacky situations to workaround limits in ASP.NET.

Comment: Well I call it with a data source:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

Html part of the page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="test" NavigateUrl="<%# GetUrl() %>" runat="server">test</asp:HyperLink>
```

Code behind:

```
protected string GetUrl()
{
    //Put your logic here to generate dynamicly url that you want
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Best regards, Dima.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark, but the `<%#` and `%>` tags indicate that you want to run data binding code (as in, something you've returned from the database).

You don't need these to output a string literal, but if you did, the appropriate tag would be `<%=`, not `<%#`.

Comment: When I use `<%=` it gives me following code in output: `<a href="<%="http://google.pl"%>">test</a>`

Comment: I've never tried to use that tag in a NavigateUrl property before (I didn't mean to imply that you should use that tag, and I'll edit the answer shortly to clarify that), but again, you don't need to use the ASP.NET tags to assign a string literal to your NavigateUrl property.

Comment: Yes I know but I want to get that address for example from some class: UrlParams.Google. I want then to do: `NavigateUrl='<%="http://google.pl" + UrlParams.Google%>'` but it does not work.

Comment: Err...that's totally different than what you posted in the question. If UrlParams.Google contains a querystring and isn't part of a DataBound control, then you need to handle this on the server-side part of your webpage.